# Print comparison as a number instead true or false in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm putting a array inside a filter to create another array that stores all of the numbers that get through the filter but I don't know how.

Here is my code that creates the filter:

```
def check(list1):
    # traverse the list
    for x in list1:
        if 80 >= x <= 100 :
            return True

    return False

list1 = X2[indexes2]
print check(list1)
```

Comment: A number less than 80 or equals to 80 will always be less than 100.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another array within `check()`, and append values that pass the filter to it and return that list back.

Also, you have a logic error in your comparison statement; you're checking if `x` is less than 80 and less than 100. If you want to check whether `x` falls between 80 and 100, then do:

```py
if 80 <= x <= 100 :
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this.

»  I have tried it in Python2 as I saw the tags are related to that. You can try the same with Python3 as well.

> 1st way

```
>>> def check(x):
...     return 80 <= x <= 100: # x >= 80 and x <= 100 
... 
>>> l = [34, 67, 80, 21, 102, 100, 456, 99]
>>> 
>>> l2 = filter(check, l)
>>> l2
[80, 100, 99]
>>>
```

> 2nd way

```
>>> def check(lst):
...     lst2 = []
...     for x in lst:
...         if 80 <= x <= 100: # x >= 80 and x <= 100
...             lst2.append(x)
...     return lst2
... 
>>> l = [1, 54, 81, 65, 100, 99, 32, 80, 45, 95]
>>> l2 = check(l)
>>> l2
[81, 100, 99, 80, 95]
```

Comment: Why not write the condition as `80 <= x <= 100`? And why not replace the `if ...: return True; else: return False` with just `return ...`?

Comment: Be careful with the direction of the comparison: (under normal circumstances,) `x >= 80 and x <= 100` is equivalent to `80 <= x and x <= 100`, which is equivalent to `80 <= x <= 100`. `80 >= x <= 100` is equivalent to `80 >= x and x <= 100`, which is equivalent to `x <= 80 and x <= 100`.

Comment: That's great Solomon. Thank you.

Comment: Also, in your first way, what I said that you can replace `if ...: return True; else: return False` with just `return ...`. There's no need for an `if` statement there. In this case, all you need in the function's body is `return 80 <= x <= 100`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to create a new list by filtering a given list with a condition:

```
print([x for x in X2[indexes2] if 80 <= x <= 100])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's builtin filter for this:

```
bool(len(list(filter(lambda x: x <= 80, i))))
```

beware that your initial comparison was doing `x <= 80` and `x <= 100`, obviously could be simplified to `x <= 80`

Comment: Notice less than / greater than usages.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient one-line implementation would be `print(any(map(lambda x: x <= 80, X2[indexes2])))`. (`80 <= x <= 100` is probably what you meant to use.)